# how to fill the junction

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need a reverse and distorted letter "D" , the following picture has blank in the line junction.

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames,11pt]{scrartcl}
    \usepackage{tikz,pgfornament,tikzrput}         % altermundus.com/pages/tkz/tikzrput/

    \begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}

    \draw  [line width=2mm,line cap = round, red] (0,3) ..controls (-4,1) and (-5,-2) .. (0,-3);
    \draw  [line width=2mm,rounded corners, red] (0,3) --(0,-3);

    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

merge both line into one. two examples:

- with round line join (red line)
- without rounding line join (blue line)

for join line use `cycle` for the last line coordinate

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames,11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfornament,tikzrput}         % altermundus.com/pages/tkz/tikzrput/

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [line width=2mm,line join = round, red] (0,3) ..controls (-4,1) and (-5,-2) .. (0,-3) -- cycle;
    \begin{scope}[xshift=44mm]
\draw [line width=2mm,blue] (0,3) ..controls (-4,1) and (-5,-2) .. (0,-3) -- cycle;
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]